# Welche Präposition ist passender für den Abschnitt "Als Ersatz zu oder für"?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Daneben gab es Naturgeld wie Lebensmittel, Butterziegel, Gewürze,
>   Schafswolle, Pelze, Häute, Kokosnüsse, Mandeln oder Olivenöl:
>   Gegenstände, die in einer bestimmten Region vorkamen und dort
>   ebenfalls großen Wert besaßen. Sie verfeinerten Speisen oder wärmten
>   im Winter als Mantel und Beinkleid. Diese Naturerzeugnisse, auch
>   Naturalien , konnten wie Vieh oder Feldfrüchte als Zahlungsmittel
>   kaputt gehen, sterben, verderben, ranzig werden. Daher kann man sie
>   neben Waffen, Schmuck oder Münzen als komplementär, sprich, **als
>   Ersatzwährung zur** eigentlichen Währung ansehen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn die Frage wäre, ob es *Ersatz zu* oder *Ersatz für* heißen muss, wie der Titel nahelegt, wäre ich für *für*.

Hier wird aber m. E. *zur* verwendet, weil diese Ersatzwährung die echte Währung nicht verdrängt, sondern als Alternative daneben gestellt wird. Das ist eine andere Art von Ersatz als beim Ersatzrad, das das defekte ersetzt.

Dazu passt: Das ergiebigste Wikipedia-Stichwort ist [Komplementärwährung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komplement%C3%A4rw%C3%A4hrung), während [Ersatzwährung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzw%C3%A4hrung) ziemlich dünn ist.

Comment: Der Ausdruck »Ergänzungswährung« wäre also passender. [»Ersatz für ...«](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ersatz), aber [»Ergänzung zu ...«](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ergaenzung).

Comment: Eher ein Zusatz als ein Ersatz. ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  ist die Frage jetzt schon erklärt?

Comment: @user26646: Das Wort "Ersatzwährung" ist m.E. falsch. Ich würde sagen "Komplementärwährung *zu* X".

Comment: @Raketenolli ist diese Frage jetzt schon nach der Umformulierung erklärt ?

Comment: Ich weiß zwar nicht warum Du mich ansprichst, aber was ich wohl genau so wie Rudy ausdrücken wollte war, dass Dein zweiter Absatz richtig und wichtig zur Beantwortung der Frage ist: Es wäre entweder eine __»Ersatzwährung für«__ die eigentl. Währung, ist es aber nicht, weil sie diese nicht vollständig verdrängt, daher ist sie eine __»Ergänzungs- oder Komplementärwährung zur«__ eigentl. Währung. *»Ersatzwährung zur ...«* ist m. E. falsch, siehe meine beiden Duden-Links weiter oben.